# How can I forward a dynamic URL to twitter using .htaccess or PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a dynamic URL. The content `myurl` and `mytext` is always different and should be insert in the "text" and "url" from the Twitter string.

This is the string:

```
http://example.com/share/?myurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&mytext=helloworld
   /* forward to: */
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=Example%3Aname&text=helloworld&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&via=example
```

How can that be made? (I browsed the `.htaccess` suggestions but couldn't find a solution for my specific problem.)

Comment: Does browsing _".htaccess suggestions"_ mean that you want to do this within your .htaccess file?

Comment: Dont know If I get it right..you should check the $_GET array for "myurl" and "mytext" variables and append them wherever you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be more efficient to handle it with rewrite Rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^myurl=(.*)&mytext=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=Example%3Aname&text=%2&url=%1&via=example [R,L]
```

If you want this to be permanent redirect then replace R with R=301.

With permanent redirects , these links will always be redirected by browser and your server will have to deal with less traffic if that is desired.

Comment: OK that sounds odd - I use .htaccess now. Only thing is: How can I replace "%20" (spaces) with a "+" (plus sign)? Twitter seems to need this otherwise the text isn't readable. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if text/characters in query part can be substituted by mod_rewrite. However mod_rewrite does support to replace characters in URL other than query string. In that case you should stick with your php implemenation.

Answer (score 2):

Does your server support PHP?

You could just put something like the following in a PHP file:

```
Header("Location: http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=Example%3Aname&text=$_GET['mytext']&url=$_GET['myurl']&via=example");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I go on with the PHP idea.

Comment: I do not recommend this approach for websites having to deal with lots of traffic. Rewrites are better dealt with rules.